# the use of XMLString::release( XMLCh ** buf)

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, xerces-c

I'm using xerces-c++ I don't seem to really get the use of `XMLString::release ( XMLCh ** buf)` so right now I'm using it every time I want to reuse a local variable like this:

```
XMLCh* xmlStringVar = XMLString::Transcode("name");
XMLCh* fieldName = fieldsNodeList[NbreFlds]->getAttribute(xmlStringVar));
XMLString::release(&xmlStringVar);
xmlStringVar = XMLString::Transcode("id");
XMLCh* fieldId = fieldsNodeList[NbreFlds]->getAttribute(xmlStringVar));
```

please correct to me this code if something is wrong and if you got a clearer description of the function `XMLString::release` please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks perfectly valid. As the documentation for [XMLString::release](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLString.html#e7f80620bc8b3e3e3e5ea0fc14d5fe5f) says use it to free memory allocated by the transcode() function.

Answer (score 1):

Xerces documentation says: "The implementation will call MemoryManager::deallocate and **then turn the string to a null pointer.**"
To assign the string to a null pointer it requires address of the string pointer. If it was deallocation only, passing pointer (instead of address of the pointer) would be sufficient.

Comment: how is that even possible !? once MemoryManager::deallocate is launched , the variable doesn't exist anymore it's deleted for good , so how does it turn the variable again to a null pointer after it deleted it !

Comment: Actually the **memory space pointed by the pointer** is deleted, not the pointer itself. After this deletion, the pointer becomes a dangling pointer which means it points to an invalid memory location. In order to prevent accessing an invalid memory, it is a good practice to assign the dangling pointer to null.

Comment: ok, it seems reasonable now! thanks a lot that was really helpful.